# Order by datetime, leaving empty times at the end

Tags: mysql

It's a database for advertisers to contact their customers that needs to be ordered by criteria:

1. If date is not specified it's an irrelevant contact and should be listed at the bottom.
2. If date is specified but time is not, then it should be listed at the bottom of that date.

Field 'contact_request' is DATETIME

Thus, goal:

1. Dateless entries (0000-00-00 00:00:00) should be listed at the end of the table.
2. Timeless entries (%00:00:00) should be listed at the end of the date.

So desired result is like this (00:00:00 at the end, otherwise sorted ASC):

```
2017-01-21 09:00:00 | 1
2017-03-21 00:00:00 | 2
2017-03-22 11:00:00 | 3
2017-01-18 10:00:00 | 4
2017-03-21 10:00:00 | 5
0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 6
0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 7
```

This makes the wrong sequence (4,1,5,3,2,.. instead of correct 4,1,5,2,3,..):

```
ORDER BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN contact_request = '0000-00-00' THEN 3 
    WHEN contact_request NOT LIKE '%00:00:00' THEN 1 
    ELSE 2 
  END, 
  contact_request ASC
```

Can't figure out how to do it?

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c6c3/6 (without '0000-00-00 00:00:00' that throws an error there, but that's an easy one anyway)

Comment: So the data type is string? not datetime?  You're going to need to split out date/time.  When time is 00:00:00 you need to make it 24:00:00 since there is no such time.  then it will sort correctly. but this assumes string data.  So if date is not 000's and time is zero's then replace 00:00:00 in time to 24:00:00 assuming 24 hour date format.

Comment: hint: put your CASE in the SELECT list - and use that to order

Comment: Repeating the same content over and over again in your post is useless. Please don't do so. If you're doing it to bypass the minimum text restrictions, don't. Instead, do a better job of explaining your problem  or question. If you're not doing it for that reason, stop doing it anyway. It's unnecessary noise and clutter that should be removed.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @KenWhite I hoped that I had a clear question, but I understand your point. Hope I improved it. 
To Strawberry I added a fiddle, maybe it makes the question easier to answer.
I thought I'd thoroughly googled for an answer, and couldn't find one. Is it really so irrelevant a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aregetting that result because you are giving all timestamps with not qualified time the same value, thus grouping all of them at the end, before the not qualified dates.

Your `case` statement has to be a bit more complex to achieve what you desire:

```
ORDER BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN contact_request = '0000-00-00' THEN 1
    ELSE 2 
  END, /* not qualified dates at the end */
  DATE_FORMAT(contact_request , '%Y%m%e'), /* then order by day */
  CASE 
    WHEN contact_request LIKE '%00:00:00' THEN 2
    ELSE 1
  END, /* not qualified times at the end of each day */
  contact_request /* finally order by whole timestamp */
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works as it should! Just needs replacing 'THEN 2' with 'THEN 3' at line 3.

Comment: Just one problem though: can't seem to sort descending now: look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c6c3/4

Comment: If you want the order to be descending but keeping the 00:00 at the bottom, you have to add `desc` after the second and fourth ordering conditions. If you want the complete opposite ordering, you have to add `desc` after all the four conditions

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
IF(contact_request = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    ,'9999-12-31 23:59:59'
    ,IF(TIME(contact_request) = '00::00:00'
            , ADDTIME('2017-01-01 00:00:00','23:59:59')
            , contact_request  ) ASC;
```

Comment: This doesn't address the sorting those contact requests with a date but 00:00:00 time to end of that day. (2nd requirement)

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY 
CASE when replace(CONTACT_REQUEST,'00:00:00','24:00:00) = '0000-00-00 24:00:00' 
     then 2 else 1 end
```

Assuming string datatype for contact_Request.

This works because the date is stored as string and 24 isn't a valid time but 00 being made into 24 for hour would put it last in each day